# Query on __repr__ method of a class in python

Tags: python

After running below code, as `>>> python -i sample.py` on a shell

```
class Coordinate(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        print('In init')
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

    def __repr__(self):
        print('In __repr__')
        return "Coord: " + str(self.__dict__)

def add(a, b):
    return Coordinate(a.x + b.x, a.y + b.y)

def sub(a, b):
    return Coordinate(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y)

Coordinate(100, 200)
Coordinate(300, 200)
```

i see the output as

```
PS C:\mystuff> python -i .\sample.py
In init
In init
>>>
```

In continuation with that interpreter session, if i call the constructor again, as shown below,

```
>>> Coordinate(100, 200)
In init
In __repr__
Coord: {'y': 200, 'x': 100}
>>>
```

I see control goes into `__repr__()` method.

My question:
Why are we not entering into `__repr__()` method, when we call `Coordinate(100, 200)` from  sample.py file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because you are not explicitly calling any `print` function in the `.py` file. In the python interpreter, when you write a sentence, it prints the result immediately after, so it goes into the `__repr__` function.

If you do a `print` statement within your `.py` code, the string returned by `__repr__` will be printed, unless you have implemented the `__str__` function, which is more of an "informal" and usually shorter string representation of the object. `__repr__` should be a valid python expression, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__). If no `__repr__` or `__str__` methods are implemented in your class, by default, python interpreter does not know how to print the contents of your class, so it just prints that: `<Coordinate object at 0x0000...>`.

Comment: print() function internally uses __repr__() method? i mean, if i remove __repr__() method from the class, i see the output as ---->>> Coordinate(100, 200)
In init
<__main__.Coordinate object at 0x00000000025E0B70>
>>>---------

Comment: the string returned by `__repr__` will be printed, unless you have implemented the `__str__` function, which is more of an "informal" string representation of the object. `__repr__` should be a valid python expression, according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__). If no `__repr__` or `__str__` methods are provided, by default you get that sort of output `<coordinate object at 0x0000...>`.

Comment: cnluzon so print() is invoked on  object created on calling Coordinate(100, 200) ---- something like print(Coordinate(100, 200))?----Becasue now i see the output as 
PS C:\mystuff> python -i .\sample.py
In init
In __repr__
Coord: {'y': 200, 'x': 100}
In init
In __repr__
Coord: {'y': 200, 'x': 300}
>>>------becasue i changed the file content as print(Coordinate(100, 200))
print(Coordinate(300, 200))

Comment: You mean that you put `print(Coordinate(100,200))` in your `.py` file and now you get that the `__repr__` function is called, right? Print is **not** invoked on the creation of an object. However, when you write any expression in the python interpreter, this expression is evaluated and printed right away. It's the interpreter who prints the results of your expression for you, not the constructor of the Coordinate class.

Comment: by the way, if the answer solved your question, feel free to accept it.

Comment: YES! Excellent tip. Helped me solve django-polymorphic problem.